# Enabling Auto-Renewal for Azure Reservation Using PowerShell Script

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have Azure reservations for various services, and I'm looking to automate the process of enabling auto-renewal for these reservations using PowerShell scripting. I want to ensure that my reservations are automatically renewed to prevent service interruptions.

Is there a PowerShell script that can be used to enable auto-renewal for Azure reservations? If so, could you please provide an example script and any necessary steps to use it?

I appreciate any guidance or assistance on how to achieve this automation.

i tried but my script didn't worked.

```
if ($reservation) {
    # Check the auto-renewal status for the reservation     
    $autoRenewalStatus = $reservation.Renew
    
    if ($autoRenewalStatus -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Auto-renewal is already enabled for the reservation with ID $reservationId."
    } else {
        # Attempt to force enable auto-renewal for the reservation         
        try { 
            Set-AzReservation -ReservationId $reservationId -Renew $true -Force 
            Write-Host "Auto-renewal has been successfully forced enabled for the reservation with ID $reservationId."
        } catch { 
            Write-Host "Failed to force enable auto-renewal for the reservation with ID $reservationId. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the reservation panel, there is a button for "Automatically purchase a new reservation upon expiry". Please check this article out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/reservation-renew

Comment: but i want script, i've more than 2000 reservation i can't do it manually.